# How to use NgRx entity updateOne or updateMany with effects?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

I'm new to NgRx entities... And don't know how to take advantage of it in order to update my state. I just like to satisfy my action right in my effect.

This is my effect:

```
updateItem$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ItemsActions.updateItem),
      concatMap(({ url, item }) => {
        return this._itemsProxy.updateItem(url, item).pipe(
          map((item: { id:number; name: string; }) => {

            // I get an error that says:
            // Type '{ id: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Update<{ id:number, name: string }>'
            // So how should I satisfy my action?

            return ItemsActions.updateItemSuccess({ item })
          }),
          catchError((error) => of(ItemsActions.failure({ error }))),
        );
      }),
    ),
  );
```

This is my action group:

```
export const ItemsActions = createActionGroup({
  source: 'Items/API',
  events: {
    updateItem: props<{ url: string; item: { id: number; name: string; } }>(),
    updateItemSuccess: props<{ item: Update<{ id: number; name: string; }> }>(),
    failure: props<{ error: string }>(),
  },
});
```

This is my reducer stuff:

```
export interface ItemsState extends EntityState<{ id: number; name: string; }> {
  selectedId?: string | number | null;
  loaded: boolean;
  error?: string | null;
}

export interface ItemsPartialState {
  readonly [ITEMS_FEATURE_KEY]: ItemsState;
}

export const itemsAdapter: EntityAdapter<{ id: number; name: string; }> = createEntityAdapter<{ id: number; name: string; }>();

export const initialItemsState: ItemsState = itemsAdapter.getInitialState({
  loaded: false,
});

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialItemsState,

  on(ItemsActions.updateItem, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    loaded: false,
    error: null,
  })),
  on(ItemsActions.updateItemSuccess, (state, { item }) => {

    // Yea! Currently item type is { id: number; name: string; }
    // And that doesn't work with updateOne method.

    return itemsAdapter.updateOne(item, {
      ...state,
      loaded: true,
      error: null,
    });
  }),
);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`updateOne` and  `updateMany` want you to specify `id` and `changes`.

Here the docs: [Entity Updates](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter#entity-updates).

So your code will be:

```
on(ItemsActions.updateItemSuccess, (state, { item }) => {
    return itemsAdapter.updateOne(
        { id: item.id, changes: item },
        { ...state, loaded: true, error: null }
    );
}),
```